# ReactJS Sending selection back up to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know we send data into child components through props, but how does one send data back up to the parent?

I have a a series of dropdown boxes where an item can be selected:

**DropdownMenu.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class DropdownMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            highlight: false,
            count: this.props.count || 0,
            selection: null
        }
        this.showDropdown = this.showDropdown.bind(this);
        this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    showDropdown() {

    }

    selectItem(e) {

    }

    render() {
        return <div className="dropdown__menu" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            {this.props.text} {this.state.count > 0 ? <b>{this.state.count}</b> : ''}
            <div className="dropdown__content"
                 style={this.props.isOpen ? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'none'}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Which is called from **CompanyList.js**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sortBy: null,

...

<DropdownMenu text="Sort by" isOpen={this.state.activeDropdown === "Sort_by"}
                                  onClick={this.showDropdown.bind(this, "Sort_by")}
                                  onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({mouseInDropdown: true})}
                                  onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({mouseInDropdown: false})}>
                        <div onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({mouseInDropdown: true})}
                             onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({mouseInDropdown: false})}>
                            <li>Name</li>
                            <li>Age</li>
                            <li>Value</li>
                        </div>
                    </DropdownMenu>
...
```

---

Thanks for the replies but how do I apply the function to each of the `<li>` that are children of the dropdown (some dropdowns may not have any options and are just buttons)?

```
this.props.children
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR --> https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Just pass a callback from the parent to the child :

```
// parent component
(...)
myCallback(arg1){
    this.setState({val:arg1});
}

render(){

    return(
        <MyChildComponent onSpecificAction={this.myCallback.bind(this)} />
    );
}
(...)

// child component
(...)
render(){

    return(
        <button onclick={(e) => this.props.onSpecificAction('value to send up')}>Button text</button>
    );
}
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you are passing props to a child element, you can also pass functions.

So you can pass a function like `onChange(newData)` from the parent to your child component that you will call everytime the value changes.